# Is it wise to use MVVM with a static screen in iOS?

Tags: ios, design-patterns, mvvm

I have a very basic screen with few labels containing informative/static text (which will never change), an image and two buttons.

Tapping on first button should lead to a second screen. Tapping on second button should lead to a third screen.

Is it wise to use MVVM design pattern in such a simple use case? Or shall I just create the scene in Storyboard - hard code the label texts and image in UIImageView, have segues for the two buttons to lead to respective second or third screens?

If I intend to use MVVM, how shall I be doing it? What should go into the model and view model classes?

Comment: If you have no model and no business logic, the only rationale to implement MVVM would be consistency and/or a placeholder for future view model (VM). This is a matter of personal opinion (and, as such, is not the sort of discussion that is encouraged on StackOverflow). All I’ll say is that I’ve worked on an app with a similarly empty landing page, it had no VM, and we never felt terribly compelled to go back and add any empty VM scaffolding. But don’t be surprised if you later find yourself adding a VM (initializing services to be injected elsewhere, warming up caches, A/B testing, etc.).

Comment: “If I intend to use MVVM, how shall I be doing it?” ... This is (a) a completely different question; and (b) is far too broad. And if you decide you want to post a separate question on that topic, that you post a new question indicating what research you’ve done, showing us what you tried, and let us know what’s not working. (And if you just want a review of a working MVVM attempt for which you’re soliciting feedback, then this isn’t the right forum, anyway, and it might be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com.)